Where is the following Shloka about Gandharva Vivaha found?
गन्धर्वो विवाहः संज्ञो यः प्रेम्णा स्वेच्छया कृतः। अन्योन्यस्नेहसंयुक्तौ युवयोर्यः स समाहितः
Can someone point out the source of this verse Meta AI says it is from harita smriti but i am unable to find it..please someone point out..thanks
